# qt rubberband selection with specific keyboard key

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, rubber-band

I have a `QGraphicsView` and a `QGraphicsScene` and I enabled

```
this->setDragMode(QGraphicsView::RubberBandDrag);
```

for a Rubberband selection. However, in my application it would make sense that you need to press the CTRL key and then move the mouse to start the rubberband selection. Can I accomplish this without making my own QRubberBand? If not, how can I reimplement it?

Answer (score 4):

If you have say a `QMainWindow` that contains your `QGraphicsView` and Scene, one way to do this would be to overload the `keyPressEvent` and `keyReleaseEvent` methods of QMainWindow like this:

```
void MyMainWindow::keyPressEvent( QKeyEvent * event )
{
  if( event->key() == Qt::Key_Control ) {
    graphicsView->setDragMode(QGraphicsView::RubberBandDrag);
  }
  QMainWindow::keyPressEvent(event);

}


void MyMainWindow::keyReleaseEvent( QKeyEvent * event )
{
  if( event->key() == Qt::Key_Control ) {
    graphicsView->setDragMode(QGraphicsView::NoDrag);
  }
 QMainWindow::keyReleaseEvent(event);

}
```

This will set the selection mode to `RubberBandDrag` as long as CTRL is being pressed. When the key is released again, the drag mode is set back to the default `NoDrag` and no selection is performed. 
In both cases the event is also forwarded to the QMainWindow base class implementation which may or may not be of relevance for you.

Comment: @Amazonasmann I was wondering if this answer solved your problem or if there is something missing from it? Or maybe the question in any case is no longer of relevance to you?

Comment: I'm having an issue with this approach, if I switch Drag mode while dragging, the rubber band gets frozen in the screen, even after releasing the mouse button.

Comment: @AdrielJr not sure I understand the question. What do you mean with switching the mode while dragging? Releasing the control key in the middle of the movement? Sth else?

Comment: You start dragging with the mouse so that you see the white selection rectangle on the screen, than, without releasing the mouse button, you call setDragMode(QGraphicsView::NoDrag). That is it, you have a frozen white rectangle on your screen until you set the drag mode back to rubber band and start dragging again. There are a few issues in QT Bug track service about this bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51105 https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-65186 https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-2132

Answer (score 2):

Erik's answer didn't work well for me. If I release the key while still dragging, the rubber band is not cleared and remains visible on the screen until the next selection.

Because QT only clears the rubber band on mouse release, my workaround was to force an artificial mouse release event while still in Rubberband mode to have it properly cleared:

```
void MyQGraphisView::keyReleaseEvent( QKeyEvent * event )
{
    if( event->key() == Qt::Key_Control ) {
        if(QApplication::mouseButtons() & Qt::LeftButton)
            mouseReleaseEvent(new QMouseEvent(QApplicationStateChangeEvent::MouseButtonRelease, mousePosOnScene, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoButton, Qt::NoModifier));   
        setDragMode(QGraphicsView::NoDrag);
    }
    QMainWindow::keyReleaseEvent(event);

}
```

Update: Qt fixed this bug (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-65186) and will be deployed in 5.15